# R ggsunburst - installation error

Tags: python, r, r-package, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to install ggsunburst package by following [these](http://genome.crg.es/~didac/ggsunburst/ggsunburst.html#install) instructions. When I run the following install package command I get the following error:

`install.packages("http://genome.crg.es/~didac/ggsunburst/ggsunburst_0.0.10.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")`

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/urwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'http://genome.crg.es/~didac/ggsunburst/ggsunburst_0.0.10.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 646077 bytes (630 KB)
>   downloaded 630 KB
>
> - installing *source* package 'ggsunburst' ...
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading
>     Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.4.4
>     ** help
>     *** installing help indices
>     converting help for package 'ggsunburst'
>     finding HTML links ... done
>     ggsunburst                              html
>
>     ggtree                                  html
>
>     icicle                                  html
>
>     nw_print                                html
>
>     sunburst                                html
>
>     sunburst_data                           html
>
>     tile                                    html
>
>     ** building package indices
>     ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>     *** arch - i386
>     Error : package 'rPython' is not installed for 'arch = i386'
>     Error: loading failed
>     Execution halted
>     *** arch - x64
>     Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.4.4
>     ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
> - removing 'C:/Users/urwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggsunburst'
>     In R CMD INSTALL
>     Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\urwa\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" "C:/Users/urwa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeSU5b9/downloaded_packages/ggsunburst_0.0.10.tar.gz"' had status 1
>     Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/urwa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeSU5b9/downloaded_packages/ggsunburst_0.0.10.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

EDIT 1:

I should have mentioned this I have already I installed rPython. The error message while installing ggburst is after successful installation of rPython. I have installed rPython following [these](https://github.com/cjgb/rPython-win) instructions. I got the following message:

> Installing rPython
>   Installing 1 package: RJSONIO
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/urwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/RJSONIO_1.3-0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 1502339 bytes (1.4 MB)
>   downloaded 1.4 MB
>
> package ‘RJSONIO’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>       C:\Users\urwa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwJlp4O\downloaded_packages
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
>     "C:/Users/urwa/Downloads/rPython" --library="C:/Users/urwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests
>
> *installing *source* package 'rPython' ...
>
> ** libs
>
> Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
>   so building only the main architecture
>
> make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>
> installing to C:/Users/urwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rPython/libs/x64
>
> ** R
>
> ** inst
>
> ** preparing package for lazy loading
>
> ** help
>
> *** installing help indices
>
> converting help for package 'rPython'
>
> finding HTML links ... done
>      python.assign                           html
>      python.call                             html
>      python.exec                             html
>      python.load                             html
>   ** building package indices
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>   * DONE (rPython)
>   In R CMD INSTALL

**MY SYSTEM SPECS**

- Window 10 x64
- R Studio 1.1.423
- R 3.4.3
- Python 3.6.5

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

I updated R to 3.5.0. Reinstalled ggplot2. Rerun the installation of ggburst. The error is still the same with ggplot part omitted. Here is the complete output:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/urwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://genome.crg.es/~didac/ggsunburst/ggsunburst_0.0.10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 646077 bytes (630 KB)
downloaded 630 KB

* installing *source* package 'ggsunburst' ...
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'ggsunburst'
    finding HTML links ... done
    ggsunburst                              html  
    ggtree                                  html  
    icicle                                  html  
    nw_print                                html  
    sunburst                                html  
    sunburst_data                           html  
    tile                                    html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error : package 'rPython' is not installed for 'arch = i386'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/urwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggsunburst'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/urwa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpS60ZhD/downloaded_packages/ggsunburst_0.0.10.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: welp...did you install `rPython`?

Comment: @uvar .I had `rPython` installed before installing `ggburst`. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Depends: R (>= 3.0.2), rPython (>= 0.0-4), ggplot2 (>= 2.2.1); I can see the rPython requirement is cleared, the R requirement is cleared.    Now for the ggplot2. Actually, the message appears to be telling you that ggplot has been installed for R 3.4.4, while you are using 3.4.3. Any chance you might have backwards compatibility issues?

Comment: @Uvar. I updated R to 3.5.0. Reinstalled ggplot2. Rerun the installation of ggburst. The error is still the same with ggplot part omitted. Here is the complete output. https://pastebin.com/qNQEEKam

Comment: Tch...unfortunately I am not at all a guru when it comes to operating systems. It seems like the system architecture and package expectations are not in line. The `arch i386` is referring to a specific type. You might try `library(devtools)
options(devtools.install.args = "--no-multiarch")` and then re-running the install. If that does not work, it goes way over my head I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. First, install package **devtools** then using code that @Uva suggested above

```
library(devtools) 
options(devtools.install.args = "--no-multiarch")
devtools::install_github("didacs/ggsunburst")
```